# Как в js получить путь до текущей директории на wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Кастомизировал метки на карте, вот часть кода в файле js

```
iconImageHref: 'img/label_map.png'
```

Прикручиваю на вордпресс и если бы это был php, я бы просто написал:

```
iconImageHref: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/label_map.png'
```

Или типо того, и вордпресс автоматически выставил мне правильный путь.
Но это файл JS, как сделать так, чтобы путь до нужного файла находился автоматически и не пришлось выставлять вручную (так и ошибиться можно)

Comment: /wp-content/themes/название_темы/img/label_map.png

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Сделайте это ответом, я отмечу правильным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/wp-content/themes/название_темы/img/label_map.png